# Cannot refresh canvas - pass through draw but doesn't change

Tags: android, android-widget

I have problem with refreching canvas in my widget. I create custom widget and I want to repaint first cell on click.
There ins activity

```
public class TestView extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ElementView ev = (ElementView)findViewById(R.id.surface2);
        ev.setOnClickListener(evOnClick);

    }

    public OnClickListener evOnClick = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ElementView temp=(ElementView)v;
            temp.paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            temp.canvas.drawRect(new Rect(0,0,90,90),temp.paint);
            temp.postInvalidate();
        }
        };
}
```

and there is ElementView ( widget which I want to repaint )

```
public class ElementView extends View {
    private final int width=100;
    private final int height=100;
    public Paint paint=null;
    public Canvas canvas=null;

    public ElementView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    public ElementView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);
        paint = new Paint();
    }


    public ElementView(Context context, AttributeSet attr, int defaultStyles) {
        super(context, attr, defaultStyles);
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        int measuredWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
        int measuredHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(this.width,this.height);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas=canvas;
        // get the size of your control based on last call to onMeasure
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();
        int width = getMeasuredWidth();

        // Now create a paint brush to draw your widget

        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        //define border
        this.canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 0, 99, paint);
        this.canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 99,0, paint);
        this.canvas.drawLine(99, 0, 99, 99, paint);
        this.canvas.drawLine(0, 99, 99,99, paint);

        //define cells
        this.canvas.drawLine(0,50,99,50,paint);
        this.canvas.drawLine(30,0,30,50,paint);

        //draw green rectangle
        this.canvas.drawRect(new Rect(0,0,50,50),paint);
        //draw some text
        paint.setTextSize(8);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        String displayText = "test";


        Float textWidth = paint.measureText(displayText);

        int px = width / 2;
        int py = height / 2;
        this.canvas.drawText(displayText, px - textWidth / 2, py, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        //change color of first cell
        canvas.drawRect(new Rect(0,0,50,50),paint);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

}

When I click on ElementView it enter in Activity in onClick and pass through code without mistake or exception , but doesn't change view . Can anybody tell me where is mistake ?

Comment: if you got the answer..and if it is working please add that piece of code as "Edit" in your Question section...so that others can also learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think writing to the `Canvas` outside of the `onDraw` method will have any effect on the screen.

Try setting a flag in your `onClick` method that you read in `onDraw` which will trigger your drawing routine.

Comment: what do you mean by setting a flag..I believe that the onDraw method in the view is overridden by some invocation..can that be explicitly called from outside ?